# Multiple domain LTD's with domain forwarding with single SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, lets-encrypt

For a web application I have the same name with multiple LTD's, for example:

- MyApp.com
- MyApp.de
- MyApp.fr
- MyApp.nl
- MyApp.be

When I enter MyApp.de, I would like to be refered to MyApp.com/de, but also the next reference would be appreciated:

> subdomain.MyApp.**fr**/pages/test/1534534

to

> subdomain.MyApp.**com/fr**/pages/test/1534534

In code I can do this, the only downside is that I need a wildcard SSL certificates for all the LTD's. I can do this but I need to create certificates manually (Let's Encrypt), and I need to do that every 3 months.
If I need to do that for the 5 LTD's I have, every 3 months I need to create 10 certificates which is a lot of work but also sensitive to errors.

Is there a better way to do this, or am I stuck to create the certificates for all the LTD's?

Comment: *"I need to create certificates manually (Let's Encrypt), and I need to do that every 3 months"* - LE is specifically designed to be automated, i.e. there is no need to create the certificates *manually* every 3 month as claimed. I’m voting to close this question because it is based on false assumptions.

Comment: I do need to do that because i need to add TXT records manually and where i rent the servers they say i do need to use their control panel to add the TXT records. If i am correct (or they informed me correctly), i cannot do this other than their control panel, but please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: That's bad if your provider has no way to automate this - please update your question to reflect that limitation. It is hard to provide alternatives though since you have the explicit requirement of having these multiple domains and having all of these as wildcards. One can do this with a single certificate covering all of this but it is not much less manual effort for verification then having multiple certificates. The alternative is then only to use certificates which have a longer life time. You can buy such certificates with a life time of one year, but you don't get these for free.